# How to avoid parsing address as float in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on javascript code that parses a tab delimited document. In order to facilitate searching I need to convert those properties that are a number to a float. However, mixed fields (like an address) should maintain the status of a String.

```
for(var i2=0;i2<line1.length;i2++){
      var test = local[i2];
      if(! (typeof test === 'undefined')){
        test = test.trim();
      };
      var parsed = parseFloat(test);
      if(!isNaN(parsed)){
        if(line1[i2] === "Site Address")
          console.log("Number before:"+local[i2]+" After:"+parsed);
        object[line1[i2]]=parsed;
      }
      else{
        if(line1[i2] === "Site Address")
          console.log("before:"+local[i2]+" After:"+test);
        object[line1[i2]]=test;
      }
    }
```

This seems to work ok unless there are both numbers and chars like the following....

```
Number before:1752 E MAIN ST After:1752
```

Is there a way to do this where the above is not seen as explicitly a number?

Comment: You seem to know the position of the mixed fields, why don't you simply don't use `parseFloat()` on those fields?

Comment: Because I don't know which fields are which. It seems incredibly hard to maintain which fields are numeric which ones are mixed and which ones are neither. Also the field names may change when I interface with other sources.

Comment: Surely `(! (typeof test === 'undefined'))` is clearer as `(typeof test != 'undefined')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unary `+` operator:

```
var parsed = +test;
```

The `parseFloat()` function is OK with strings that start with a valid number that's followed by non-numeric stuff, as you've discovered.

If that seems too "hackery" you can also use the Number constructor:

```
var parsed = Number( test );
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how this unary operator would help? I will look into it in the mean time.

Comment: @Jackie well it coerces its operand to be a number. If the operand is a string, then that means it'll be parsed as a number. However, unlike the `parseInt()` function, the string has to be a completely clean number - it can't have junk at the end.

Comment: Thanks, when I use the Number(String) will invalid parsing still return NaN?

Comment: @Jackie: I don't want to sound rude, but you can open the browser's console and just try it ;) The console is super convenient for playing around and trying things out. Or http://jsfiddle.net/. Just call `Number` and pass different arguments to it to see how it behaves.

Comment: @Jackie Mr. Kling is correct, and it's really good to get in the habit of exploiting all the developer-friendly features in modern browsers, but the answer to that specific question is "yes" :)

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the input, I did in fact test after I asked and before looking at the response. You bring up a good point but I think it is also good to be explicit on these answers in case others look. I did try jsfiddle but my console.log request wasn't working (guess it was a node function) so I got a little thrown off there.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided very much test data, so answers may not be very good. You can try using a regular expression so that only things that look like numbers are treated as numbers, e.g.

```
var isNum = /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
var test  = line1[i2];

parsed = isNum.test(test)? parseFloat(test) : test;
```

The variable "test" would probaby be better named "item" or "value" or similar.